# calling a function in dll delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I would like to know if I can call a function inside of my DLL in Delphi from another Delphi DLL.

example:

My A.dll is this:

```
library circle;

 uses
   SysUtils, Classes, Math;

 {$R *.res}

 function CircleArea(const radius : double) : double; stdcall;
 begin

 end;

 exports CircleArea;

 begin
 end.
```

B.DLL is a black box where I can access only one function:

```
function calculdiameter(const radius : double) : double; stdcall;
```

How can I access `calculdiameter` from b.dll to modify the type double to decimal?

Comment: What do you want to do? Call a function in a DLL, or change the parameters from Double to Decimal? Your question is unclear. Also, please can you fix the formatting. It is currently unreadable. Please use capital letters, proper punctuation, spelling etc.

Answer (score 5):

You're welcome to call DLL functions from another DLL. Simply declare the function:

```
function calculdiameter(const radius : double) : double; stdcall; external 'b.dll';
```

Then call it:

```
function CircleArea(const radius : double) : double; stdcall;
begin
  // I don't know why you'd call this function here, but you can if you want to.
  Calculdiameter(radius);
  Result := Pi * radius * radius;
end;
```

What you *can't* do, though, is *change* the contents of the DLL. As you said, B.DLL is a black box. You can call the functions that it exports, but if what it exports isn't what you want, then you need to find what you want somewhere else.